# how to understand callbacks and async.parallel in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm very new to JavaScript and callbacks, so my apologies if this is a stupid question. Based on the [async docs for parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel), I came up with this example code that executed the expected way based on the docs:

```
async = require('async')

async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
          callback(null, 'one');
        }, 800);
    },
    function(callback){
      setTimeout(function(){
        callback(null, 'two');
      }, 100);
    }
],
    function(err, results){
      console.log(results)
    })
```

Running this with `node foo.js` prints a results array `['one', 'two']` as the docs indicate it will. The thing I don't understand is how exactly this works: when you pass `callback` as a parameter to each function and then `callback` is called as `callback(null, res)`, what exactly is being called her? I've not actually defined any function callback, nor have I passed any sort of operating callback function as a parameter, yet everything magically works fine. Am I totally missing the point here? Or is this actually the under-the-hood magic of `async`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You** are **not** the one passing `callback` to the task functions, the **async** module **is**. It's a special function that the module passes to your task functions that when called, checks if any more tasks are left.

Here is something similar to what is being done inside `async`:

```
function myParallel(tasks, finalcb) {
  var tasksLeft = tasks.length,
      results = [],
      ignore = false;

  function callback(err, result) {
    if (ignore) return;
    if (err) {
      ignore = true;
      finalcb && finalcb(err);
    } else if (--tasksLeft === 0) {
      ignore = true;
      finalcb && finalcb(null, results);
    } else
      results.push(result);
  }

  tasks.forEach(function(taskfn) {
    taskfn(callback);
  });
}

myParallel([
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(null, 'one');
    }, 800);
  },
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(null, 'two');
    }, 100);
  }
], function(err, results){
  console.log(results)
});
```